# Files.readAllBytes vs Files.lines getting MalformedInputException

Tags: java, file-io, stream

I would have thought that the following two approaches to read a file should behave equally. But they don't. The second approach is throwing a `MalformedInputException`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    try {
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("_template.txt")));
        System.out.println(content);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("_template.txt"))) {
        lines.forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.io.BufferedReader$1.hasNext(BufferedReader.java:574)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:115)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at Test.main(Test.java:19)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at java.io.BufferedReader$1.hasNext(BufferedReader.java:571)
    ... 4 more
```

What is the difference here, and how do I fix it?

Comment: One approach reads bytes, one reads text. Is your file a text file? And what is the encoding?

Comment: Moreover, the default encoding for `Files.lines()` is UTF-8. Not every byte sequence is valid UTF-8.

Comment: Well, I think I need a little help to answer your question. The file is a text file. Opened with Notepad++ it says ANSI in the status bar. Does this answer your questions?

Comment: [What every software developer should know about Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: @Phylogenesis Thanks for the link. I did read that some time ago. And I recently decided to read it again. Probably now is the right moment to read it :-D

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This has to do with [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). Computers only deal with numbers. To store text, the characters in the text have to be converted to and from numbers, using some scheme. That scheme is called the character encoding. There are many different character encodings; some of the well-known standard character encodings are ASCII, ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8.

In the first example, you read all the bytes (numbers) in the file and then convert them to characters by passing them to the constructor of class `String`. This will use the default character encoding of your system (whatever it is on your operating system) to convert the bytes to characters.

In the second example, where you use `Files.lines(...)`, the UTF-8 character encoding will be used, according to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-). When a sequence of bytes is found in the file that is not a valid UTF-8 sequence, you'll get a `MalformedInputException`.

The default character encoding of your system may or may not be UTF-8, so that can explain a difference in behaviour.

You'll have to find out what character encoding is used for the file, and then explicitly use that. For example:

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("_template.txt")),
        StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

Second example:

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("_template.txt"),
        StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

Comment: Interesting... This means that the `CharsetDecoder` used in `Files.lines()` uses `CodingErrorAction.REPORT` by default. This is not documented, and is unlike any default `Reader` provided by the JDK...

Comment: @fge `Files.lines()` creates a `CharsetDecoder` from the `Charset` that you pass it, and the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) of `CharsetDecoder` say: *The default action for malformed-input and unmappable-character errors is to report them.*

Comment: Well, this default action is pretty much overriden everywhere in the JDK :)

Comment: @fge I guess that older `Reader` classes do this differently for backward compatibility. (It's also curious that `Files.lines()` uses UTF-8 by default while most other I/O classes use the system's default charset by default). The standard classes are not very consistent in many ways...

Answer (score 6):

To complement [Jesper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29937724/1093528), what happens here (and is undocumented!) is that `Files.lines()` creates a [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) whose policy is to reject invalid byte sequences; that is, its [`CodingErrorAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CodingErrorAction.html) is set to `REPORT`.

This is unlike what happens for nearly all other `Reader` implementations provided by the JDK, whose standard policy is to `REPLACE`. This policy will result in all unmappable byte sequences to emit a [replacement character (U+FFFD)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

`Files.lines` by default uses the [UTF-8 encoding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-), whereas instantiating a new String from bytes will use the default system encoding. It appears that your file is not in UTF-8, which is why it is failing.

Check what encoding your file is using, and pass it as the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

2017 use:

```
 Charset.forName("ISO_8859_1") instead of Charsets.ISO_8859_1
```

Comment: Could you add more detail?

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes use it like this: 
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("/User/me/file.log"), Charset.forName("ISO_8859_1") )