# JavaFX Reading from file throws "InvocationTargetException"?

Tags: java, file, exception, javafx

I've been trying to understand what the issue is exactly, but whatever I do doesn't seem to work.
I have a text file that lists names along with numbers, seperated by a colon.
An example of this is:

> Betty Ross:52
>
> Angie Scotts:29
>
> Michael Rosen:72

The list is very long and comprises over 10,000 lines.

```
public class PeopleIds {
    public static int UNDEFINED_ID = -1;
    private static HashMap<String, Integer> people;

    public static void initialize() {
        people = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        System.out.println(new File("res/ids/people_ids.txt").exists());
        try {
            Files.lines(Paths.get("res/ids/people_ids.txt")).forEach(s -> {
                people.put(s.replaceAll(":.*", "").trim(), Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll(".*:", "")));
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read specified file.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static int getId(final String name) {
        final Integer id = people.get(name);
        return id != null ? id : UNDEFINED_ID;
    }
}
```

I call the `initialize` method from a `GUIController` class:

```
public class GUIController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private TableView<PersonData> personTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<PersonData, String> name;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<PersonData, Integer> limit;
    @FXML
    private TextField searchInput;
    @FXML
    private ImageView personIcon;

    private Image undefinedIcon;
    private PersonIcon icon;
    private ObservableList<PersonData> data;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        PeopleIds.initialize();
        undefinedIcon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ids/no.png"));
        name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PersonData, String>("name"));
        limit.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PersonData, Integer>("limit"));
        data = PriceData.getData();
        personTable.setPeople(data);
        searchInput.textProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            final String input = searchInput.getText();
            if (input.length() == 0) return;
            searchInput.setText(input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1).toLowerCase());
            filterSearch();
        });
    }
}
```

When I call it from this class with `PeopleIds.initialize()`, an exception is thrown, telling me that there was an exception in the application start method.

Here is what was logged in its entirety:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Confidential/bin/base/PersonGUI.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at base.PersonGUI.start(PersonGUI.java:13)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.io.BufferedReader$1.hasNext(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at base.PeopleIds.initialize(PeopleIds.java:17)
    at base.GUIController.initialize(GUIController.java:36)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    ... 24 more
Exception running application base.PersonGUI
```

I'm not sure what is going on here? I've looked into it and people have said to move the fxml file (the one that is used to format the content and is linked with the `GUIController` to the same package as the Main class, however it already is.

I've been wrestling with this issue for days to no avail. Do any of you have past experiences with this issue? If so, how did you resolve it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried to debug? does the exception really come from `PeopleIds.initialize();` or maybe rather from your variables being null in the lines below that?

Answer (score 1):

If there is an `Exception` while the file is being read, not when opening the file, an **unchecked exception** is thrown for the `Files.lines` stream operation ([`Stream.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) doesn't have a `throws` clause).

This happens here

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("res/ids/people_ids.txt")).forEach(s -> {
    people.put(s.replaceAll(":.*", "").trim(), Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll(".*:", "")));
});
```

, which you can easily see in the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

(This is caused by the wrong `Charset` being used, see [Files.readAllBytes vs Files.lines getting MalformedInputException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937600/files-readallbytes-vs-files-lines-getting-malformedinputexception) )

You don't catch this kind of exception with your `catch` clause:

```
} catch (IOException e) {
```

You need to use

```
} catch (Exception e) {
```

to catch the unchecked exceptions too.